# C# VS2005 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005. I am currently doing an import for a .CSV excel file data into my SQL Server database.

I am having some error, which I assume is related to my sql statement. Below is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);

            // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension. 
            if (strExtension != ".xls" && strExtension != ".xlsx" && strExtension != ".csv" && strExtension != ".csv")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Failed to import DEM Conflicting Role Datasheet. Cause: Invalid Excel file.');</script>");
                return;
            }

            // Generate the file name to save. 
            string dir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\rhlim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\SoD\UploadFiles\";
            string mycsv = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;
            // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(dir+mycsv);

            // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
            string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + ";Extended Properties=Text;";
            using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [TABLES] FROM" + mycsv, ExcelConnection);

            OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);

            ExcelConnection.Open();

            using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // SQL Server Connection String
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<IP>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;User ID=<UID>;Password=<PW>";

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DEMUserRoles";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('DEM User Data imported');</script>");

                }
            }
            }
        }
        else Response.Write("<script>alert('Failed to import DEM User Roles Data. Cause: No file found.');</script>");
    }
```

I am getting the error

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Description] FROM20111109164041.csv'."

while executing using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader()). Description is the last column in my database.

Anyone know what is wrong with my code? Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space between FROM and the csv file! :)

```
OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [TABLES] FROM " + mycsv, ExcelConnection);
```

That's why I always use the string.Format method, you see much better how the final string will look:

```
OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT [TABLES] FROM {0}",mycsv), ExcelConnection);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to place a blank between FROM and your CSV-File:
'[Description] FROM 20111109164041.csv'

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a string you should place it between single quotes

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * , '" + tempUid + "' as [UID] from [" + sheet1 + "]", conn);
```